# Excel - Compute the median by date and sector

Tags: excel, median

I am glad to write my first post here :)

I have a question: using excel, I need to compute the media for Date and Sector, as we can see from this short example that I have created:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32uwq.png)

I have tried with this " =MEDIAN(IF(AND($A$2:$A$11=A2;$B$2:$B$11=B2);$C$2:$C$11)) ", but it does not work, since the column "Median" is equal to zero.. How can I solve this problem?

This is my expected output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To0Gt.png)

Here the link for the test xlsx file: https://easyupload.io/lk0yy6

Comment: If you have Office 365, try replacing `IF(AND())` with `FILTER()`.

Comment: I have tried but it does not work, i think.. I have updated the question with the excel file @bugdrown

Comment: Because I do not know how to manage now the result obtained with Filter() to get the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Office 365:

*Note that I created a Table from the data and am using structured references, but you can change this to regular addressing if you prefer*

```
I4: =MEDIAN(FILTER(Table1[Value],(Table1[Date]=G4)*(Table1[Sector]=H4)))
```

[image]

*If you do not have Excel 365, you can use*

```
= MEDIAN(AGGREGATE(14,6, 1/((Table1[Date]=G4)*(Table1[Sector]=H4))*Table1[Value],ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Date]=G4)*(Table1[Sector]=H4))))))
```